# RISC-V Assembly - insert literal value of address of symbol

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, riscv

I'm exploring how to use C and RISC-V assembly together and have run against a wall.

Consider the following C program that performs matrix multiplication, with the matrices defined as `extern float*`.

```
extern float* MATR_A;
extern float* MATR_B;
extern float* MATR_C;
extern int N; //Number of values in each dimension of matrices

int mmult() {
  for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<N; j++) {
      MATR_C[i*N + j] = 0;
      for(int k=0; k<N; k++) {
        MATR_C[i*N + j] += MATR_A[i*N + k] * MATR_B[k*N + j];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've then attempted to generate an assembly file, holding the contents of the A,B matrices and the value of N. An example such file could be

```
.globl _start
.globl MATR_A
.globl MATR_B
.globl MATR_C
.globl N

.section .text
_start:
  j mmult

halt:
  nop
  j halt

.section .data
MATR_A:
  .float 1.0
  .float 2.0
  .float 3.0
  .float 4.0

MATR_B:
  .float 4.0
  .float 3.0
  .float 2.0
  .float 1.0
  
MATR_C:
  .word 0 #reserve space
  .word 0
  .word 0
  .word 0

N:
  .word 2
```

The problem is that I expect a `float*` for `MATR_A, MATR_B` and `MATR_C`, but the label `MATR_A` refers to the *value* 1.0, which is then parsed as the address of the array, which is obviously wrong. Instead, I'd like to insert the literal value of the *address* of the first element of `MATR_A` somewhere, and then refer to this value. In pseudocode, something akin to

```
MATR_A:
  .float 1.0
  .float 2.0
  ...

MATR_A_PTR:
  .lit(MATR_A) #Inserts literal value of &(MATR_A)
```

I have not been able to find a way to do this in just assembly, and I'd prefer to stay away from additional linker scripts right now. Is this possible in any way? If not, what would be the preferred way of doing it with the linker?

EDIT: To add more info, this is an excerpt of the generated ELF file, compiled with

`riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -nostdlib -nostartfiles -march=rv32if -mabi=ilp32 -O3 mmult.S mmult.c -o mmult.elf`

```
0001009c <mmult>:
   1009c:       86c1a883                lw      x17,-1940(x3) # 1119c <N>
   100a0:       09105463                blez    x17,10128 <mmult+0x8c>
   100a4:       000117b7                lui     x15,0x11
   100a8:       1307a303                lw      x6,304(x15) # 11130 <MATR_A>
   100ac:       8241af83                lw      x31,-2012(x3) # 11154 <MATR_B>
   100b0:       00289613                slli    x12,x17,0x2
   100b4:       8481ae83                lw      x29,-1976(x3) # 11178 <MATR_C>
   100b8:       00660f33                add     x30,x12,x6
   100bc:       000f0593                mv      x11,x30
   100c0:       00000e13                li      x28,0
   100c4:       000f8813                mv      x16,x31
   100c8:       000e8693                mv      x13,x29
   100cc:       00000513                li      x10,0
   100d0:       f00007d3                fmv.w.x f15,x0
   100d4:       00080713                mv      x14,x16
   100d8:       00030793                mv      x15,x6
   100dc:       00f6a027                fsw     f15,0(x13)
   100e0:       0007a687                flw     f13,0(x15)
```

Above line highlights the problem. The value in x15 (first item of MATR_A, loaded at 100a8) is used as an address whereas I want to use the value and keep 11130 in x6 (x15), and then increment this when loading new values)

Comment: *, which is then parsed as the address of the array* - "parsed" by whom? Different instructions will interpret it by different ways. For example the pseudo-instruction `la` will load it's address (that is the *value* of the `MAT_A`, and not the *content* of this address which is `1.0`). You don't show any instructions though.

Comment: I guess "parsed" was the wrong choice of word. I've added an excerpt of the generated assembly to highlight the problem I'm facing

Comment: Your C function doesn't return a value. It would make more sense to declare it as returning `void`.  (Unlike C++, it's not undefined behaviour for execution to reach the closing `}` without a `return`, though.)  But where will execution go next?  You only tailcalled it with a `j` jump, not a `call` / `jal` that passes a return address.  And it doesn't call your asm `halt` itself.

Comment: Do you actually want pointers at all?  `extern float MATR_A[];` would be compatible with how your asm put data in `.data`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I opted to using pointers instead of matrices as using matrices gave me an error in the linker, complaining `undefined reference to 'memset'`.

Comment: Regarding where execution goes next: You're right, I thought `j` also passed a return address and didn't realize it was a tail-calling jump. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Using pointers to defeat the optimizer doesn't sound like a good idea!  Use `-ffreestanding` to get GCC not to invent calls to `memset` when it wants to zero out chunks of memory.  (Or better, define an efficient `memset` it can use.)  I'm a bit surprised GCC would be inventing a memset a part of this matmul; maybe it's doing all the `MATR_C[i*N + j] = 0;` first?

Answer (score 2):

Whether `extern` or not, `float *M1P;` says I have a variable whose type is pointer to float, and so it can hold a reference to one float or an array of floats.  But the variable itself is of type pointer and a scalar not an array.  In order to use that variable, someone somewhere has to initialize it to refer to an actual one or more floats in succession, and if no one does then it will default to having the value `null`.

It is not the same as `N`, which is also a variable but distinctly of type int — certainly not a pointer.

If you wanted your matrices to be roughly equivalent to `N` (i.e. not pointers but data) that would be an array rather than a pointer to float, and that declaration would be:

`extern float M1A [];` — the extern here is required by the compiler: since the size is not provided, we can say that someone else will provide the size with use of the keyword `extern`.

or `float M1A [50];` — which creates a true array of 50 floats.

---

If you want to reproduce the pointer variables in assembly, then you can leave off the initialization just like in C, using just `.globl` alone.

But it looks like you want to supply the initialization for these pointer variables, so that would look like:

```
M1A: .float 1.0
     .float 2.0
      ...
M1P: .word M1A
```

In assembly, both `M1A` and `M1P` are labels, and labels are constants whose values refer to memory locations, so they are effectively addresses/locations.

Neither names are true variables equivalent to C, since as far as the assembler is concerned, they do not have types.

Later in the code you can get the address of the array `M1A` using:

`la t0, M1A`, which will yield the address of the array in `t0`.

If you do `lw t3, M1A`, that will dereference this address yielding a float (in the integer register `t3` — probably you'd want to load it into a float register since it is a float value, as in `flw f0, M1A, t0` (NOTE: you have to supply a temporary integer register for this pseudo instruction form, since it is needed for address generation, whereas with the above `lw`, `t3` serves as both the ultimate target and the temporary integer register for address generation)).

Or using and dereferencing the (already initialized) pointer to the array, via `lw t1, M1P`, so you can now load the 1.0 using `flw f0, 0(t1)`.

Or to break down the use of the pointer variable one more step, you can do `la t2, M1P`, followed by `lw t1, 0(t2)`, which will give you the address held in memory at location `M1P` in `t1`, and once again can do `flw f0, 0(t1)`.

Comment: Wow, I cannot believe I never tried `M1P: .word M1A`, that did the trick. I realize this isn't the best way to do it, but I wanted to try and get compiled C and hand-written assembly to interact. Thank you